# The smallest integers having $2^n$ divisors

Tags: elementary-number-theory

**Problem:**  For any integer $d > 0,$ let $f(d)$ be the smallest possible integer that has exactly $d$ positive divisors (so for example we have $f(1)=1, f(5)=16,$ and $f(6)=12$). Prove that for every integer $k \geq 0$ the number $f\left(2^k\right)$ divides $f\left(2^{k+1}\right).$

**My Solution:** We begin by observing that there must exist a prime $p$ such that $2^k-1=v_p(f(2^n))<v_p(f(2^{n+1}))=2^{\ell}-1$. Otherwise, we have $v_p(f(2^n))\ge v_p(f(2^{n+1}))$ for all prime. But this isn't possible, since $f(2^{n+1})$ has more divisors than $f(2^{n})$ (by definition). Now consider the number $N=\frac{f(2^{n+1})}{p^{2^{\ell-1}}}$. This number has $2^n$ divisors. So we must have $N\ge f(2^n)$. Now consider the number $f(2^n)p^{2^k}$. This number has $2^{n+1}$ divisors.  So we must $f(2^n)p^{2^k}\ge N\cdot p^{2^{\ell-1}}\ge f(2^n)p^{2^{\ell-1}}$. Thus we must have $N=f(2^n)$ and $\ell=k+1$. Thus we must have $f(2^n)\mid f(2^{n+1})$.

But If my solution is correct, then we have nothing special about 2. Thus I am skeptic wheteher my proof is correct or not. Can someone please point out any error?

Comment: At the risk of sounding stupid, what is $v_p$?

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying this non-standard notation. Suppose $p^a\mid n$ and $p^{a+1}\nmid n$, then $v_p(n)=a$.

Comment: @orlp See [$p$-adic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order).

Comment: This is fairly standard notation for the $p$-adic order or valuation, except that it should be $\nu_p$ (Greek letter nu).

Comment: I think that $f(p^k)$ is simply the product of the $(p-1)$th powers of the first $k$ primes. So $f(p^k)$ divides $f(p^{k+1})$ for all primes $p$.

Comment: @Tonyk I initially thougth that too. But experimenting showed that it fails pretty early.

Comment: I don't think this is correct.  Note that $f(4)=6=2\cdot 3, f(8)=24=2^3\cdot 3$.  In your argument $p=2$ but then $2^l-1=3$ and $\frac {f(8)}{2^{2^l-1}}=\frac {24}8=3$, which has $2,$ not $4$ divisors.

Comment: @TonyK:  you multiply by $p,p^2,p^4,\ldots p^{2^k}\ldots $ for each prime $p$, taking the prime that gives the smallest multiplier.  So we first do $2$, then $3$, then $2^2$, then $5,7,3^2,11,13,2^4,17,19,23,5^2,\ldots $

Comment: @RossMillikan I think it's a bit hard to read but I wrote $\frac{f(8)}{2^{2^1}}$. Basically, the exponent of $p$ isn't  $2^\ell -1$ but $2^{\ell-1}$.

Comment: @RossMillikan it is dividing by $p^{2^{l-1}}$ not $p^{2^l-1}.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do use something special about $2$, namely that it is prime:

If you replace $2$ with a different prime $q$,
you end up with
$$ f(q^n)p^{q^{k+1}-q^k}\ge f(q^{n+1})=Np^{q^{\ell}-q^{\ell-1}}\ge f(q^n)p^{q^{\ell}-q^{\ell-1}},$$
so $k\ge \ell-1$ and again $k=\ell-1$ and $f(q^{n+1})=p^{(q-1)q^k}f(q^n)$.

Comment: So it is true for any prime, not just 2?